# ON clause in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I use this following query ,it works fine,but i have doubt about why we use 'ON' in this

```
select * from test_table 
left outer join  test_table_1 on  test_table.id = test_table_1.ref_id
```

Comment: look here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

There shouldnt be any doubt, 'on' is the syntax used to express the join predicate.

Answer (score 0):

`ON` clause describe the relation between those two tables. This is the base of the join (on which fieldd you want to join the tables.)

For more refer [MySQL `JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).